# JQuery TableSort doesn't work with JQuery floatThead

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the bellow MCVE with an example table from [tablesorter@github](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter)

Clicking on the table header sorts the table. When I add this line `$('table#myTable').floatThead();` which is commented in this example then it stops working.

Any idea what the problem is and how it can be fixed?

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>JQuery table sorter with JQuery floatThead MCVE</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://rawgit.com/christianbach/tablesorter/master/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/floatthead/2.1.2/jquery.floatThead.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" border=1> 
  <thead> 
  <tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Due</th><th>Web Site</th></tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody> 
   <tr><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>jsmith@gmail.com</td><td>$40.00</td> 
   <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td></tr> 
   <tr><td>Bach</td><td>Frank</td><td>fbach@yahoo.com</td><td>$50.00</td> 
   <td>http://www.frank.com</td></tr> 
   <tr><td>Doe</td><td>Jason</td><td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td><td>$100.00</td> 
   <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td></tr> 
   <tr><td>Conway</td><td>Tim</td><td>tconway@earthlink.net</td><td>$51.00</td> 
   <td>http://www.timconway.com</td></tr> 
  </tbody> 
  </table>   

  <script type="text/javascript">
   //$('table#myTable').floatThead();
   $(document).ready(function() { $("#myTable").tablesorter(); } 
   );
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found by accident the very simple solution: The order matters! Just add `$('table#myTable').floatThead();` **AFTER** the function `tablesorter()` has been called.

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>JQuery table sorter with JQuery floatThead MCVE</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://rawgit.com/christianbach/tablesorter/master/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/floatthead/2.1.2/jquery.floatThead.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" border=1> 
  <thead> 
  <tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Due</th><th>Web Site</th></tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody> 
   <tr><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>jsmith@gmail.com</td><td>$40.00</td> 
   <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td></tr> 
   <tr><td>Bach</td><td>Frank</td><td>fbach@yahoo.com</td><td>$50.00</td> 
   <td>http://www.frank.com</td></tr> 
   <tr><td>Doe</td><td>Jason</td><td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td><td>$100.00</td> 
   <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td></tr> 
   <tr><td>Conway</td><td>Tim</td><td>tconway@earthlink.net</td><td>$51.00</td> 
   <td>http://www.timconway.com</td></tr> 
  </tbody> 
  </table>   

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { $("#myTable").tablesorter(); $('table#myTable').floatThead(); } 
   );
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Strange, any idea what the reason is?

Comment: @Carsten Not really, but what I can see is, that `floatThead` is modifying massively the header `<th>` objects.

Comment: Your header is replaced with a dummy by the time floatThead is done with it. Better let table sorter bind its events to the header and then move it out of the table.